# How to get the group by having maximum timestamp

Tags: sql, apache-drill

Below is the drill query result having all columns from HBASE.

```
+----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
|     basicid    | column1 | column2 |column3|column4|   column5    |column6  | column7 | column8 | uniqueid| column10 |column11|    timestamp     |
+----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
| basic_id/4657  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13445   | 5271     | Test   | 1546938660000    |
| basic_id/4658  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13445   | 5271     | Test   | 1546938720000    |
| basic_id/4659  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13445   | 5271     | Test   | 1546938720000    |
| basic_id/4660  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13446   | 5271     | Test   | 1546944120000    |
| basic_id/4661  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13446   | 5271     | Test   | 1546944120000    |
+----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
```

I want the distinct unique id's column elements having maximum timestamp(should be one record if same also).

So the result should give two distinct unique id's from above result set having maximum timestamp.
EX:

```
   +----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
    |     basicid    | column1 | column2 |column3|column4|   column5    |column6  | column7 | column8 | uniqueid| column10 |column11|    timestamp     |
    +----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
    | basic_id/4659  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13445   | 5271     | Test   | 1546938720000    |
    | basic_id/4661  | 4       | 408     | Test  | Test  | Centimeters  | length  | 50.0    | 60.0    | 13446   | 5271     | Test   | 1546944120000    |
    +----------------+---------+---------+------------+------------+--------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+----------+---------------------------+----------------+
```

I am trying timestamp with max function but in group by I should give all columns. If I give all it the above response I won't get.

Comment: Use Top 1 from your resultset

Answer (score 1):

Select uniqueid,max(timestamp) from mytable group by uniqueid

Comment: Actually earlier I have mentioned the wrong result, I have updated now. I want the all columns with group by of uniqueid having maximum time.

Comment: Select t1.all columns,t2.timestamp  From mytable t1 inner join (select uniqueid,max(timestamp) as timestamp from mytable group by uniqueid) t2 on t1.uniqueid=t2.uniqueid and t1.timestamp=t2.timestamp

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from (
select rank over(partition by uniqueid order by timestamp desc) as rnk
       ,uniqueid
       ,timestamp
  from table)x 
 where x.rnk=1
```